# How to reset the identity field after some numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How to reset the identity field

Query

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('table1', RESEED, 0)
```

The above query is reseting all identity field, but i want to reset from 5001 onwards.

Table1

```
id value

1 100
..
..
5000 430
6501 232
6501 343
...
```

From 5001 to 6500 (identity is not creating, so i want to reset the identity from 5000 onwards).

Expected Output

id value

```
1 100
..
..
5000 430
5001 280
...
```

How to make a query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already answered to your question 8-)

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT('table1', RESEED, 5001)
```